# Is there not much sugar and many candies in the shop?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, quantifiers

I had such a sentence:

> Are there not much sugar and candies in the shop?

And I was confuseed with "are".On the one hand it should be "are" for we combine "sugar" = "it" and "candies" = they together getting "they". "They" = "are".

But on the other hand sugar is the first of "sugar" and "candies" and it's not plural, it shoul be "is" like:

> **Is** there not much sugar **and** candies in the shop?

Or we would say "is" not with "and" but with "with":

> **Is** there not much sugar **with** candies in the shop?

Or it should look like:

> **Is** there not much sugar **and  many** candies in the shop?

Or even

> **Is** there not much sugar and **are not many** candies in the shop?

But the last one seems to be broken

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the variations of the sentence is the use of both *much* and *many* that arrives from the mix of a count noun and a non-count noun.

Also, there are two possible interpretations. One talks about a *scarcity* of ingredients, while the other talks about a *surplus* of ingredients.

I will describe the *scarcity* interpretation first.

Keeping the sentence structure as close as possible to the original, you could say this:

> Is there not much sugar **or candy** in the shop?

This sounds *slightly* odd, but it is still grammatical and understandable. Note the use of *or* rather than *and*. But, primarily, the change of the countable plural *candies* to the mass noun *candy*, which allows *much* to apply to both nouns.

Other ways of phrasing it—although the results are a more dramatic change:

> Is there only a little bit of sugar and candy in the shop?
>   Is the shop running low on sugar and candy?
>   Does the shop have a shortage of sugar and candy?

In all of these, the mass noun *candy* from the previous version remains, but *or* is changed back to *and*.

---

Now for the *surplus* of ingredients interpretation.

In this case, it's a rhetorical question that uses the negative for dramatic effect when, in fact, the opposite is true.

> She proudly opened the doors of her well-stocked store. It was brimming with so much sugar and candy that there was barely room to walk anywhere.
>
> "Behold!" she exclaimed. "Is there *not* ***much*** sugar **and** candy in the shop?"

To make this clearer, compare the final two sentences with this:

> "Behold!" she exclaimed. "Is there *not* ***a vast amount of*** sugar **and** candy in the shop?"

In *this* context, it becomes clear that *Is there not much?* actually means *Isn't there a lot?* But with the sentence entirely on its own, without any such context, it is ambiguous. The use of *much* after *is there not* is not normal, so we tend to assume it's talking about a scarcity of ingredients. Yet, at the same time, the *is there not* construction is one in which the opposite would normally be meant if *much* were replaced by something else.

Also note that where in the sentence describing a scarcity of ingredients *or* is used, in this version that describes a lot of ingredients, it goes back to *and* again.